# In which situations must I retain an object?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

First, the most simple case:

When an instance needs an object, I make a retain property. It's the only good example that comes to my mind right now.

Are there other cases where I would want to retain an object, besides in a setter for a retain Property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another example is if you need to work with an object after removing it from a collection. Collections retain their objects, and therefore have to send a `-release` message to objects when they're removed. So if you remove an object from a collection and attempt to use it, there's no guarantee that it hasn't been deallocated already.

In that case, you'd need to send `-retain` to the object while it's still in the collection to guarantee that it'd still be valid after removing it.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an object using and init or copy method, the object comes to you with a retain count of 1, so your don't need to retain those, but you do need to release them.

If you are storing it into a collection like NSArray or NSDictionary, the collection will retain it, and release it when it your remove the object. However, you still own the object, and so you will also need to release it. It's reasonable to release it after you store it.

Other than that, you are probably getting an autoreleased object, and you might want to retain it if you hope it will last beyond the current run loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

To be generic, you retain a object if you need it somewhere else.

Comment: And when you did not allocate it in the first place.

Comment: That's a bit too generic for a good answer to the question ;)